# Would it be possible to display a web-browsers view within Blender

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, image

I created a simple [WebGPU](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/webgpu-io2023/#:%7E:text=WebGPU%20is%20the%20successor%20to,GPU%20capabilities%20in%20the%20future.) renderer, for visualizing [GLTF files](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html) inside a browser.

For a more responsive experience, I synchronized Blenders viewport camera with the browser using simple TCP communication, essentially resulting in Blenders viewport being rendered with my custom render-engine inside an external browser window.

However it would be much more accessible, if the browsers view was displayed directly inside of the Blender viewport.

My first approach was using the [Selenium python package](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), saving a screenshot of a page and than reading the pixels into a [Blender Image](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image):

```
import bpy
from selenium import webdriver

# Set up the web browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run the browser in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Create an empty texture
texture_name = "Webpage Texture"
texture = bpy.data.textures.new(texture_name, type='IMAGE')
texture.use_alpha = True

# Create a material and assign the texture
material_name = "Webpage Material"
material = bpy.data.materials.new(material_name)
material.use_nodes = True
node_tree = material.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
output_node = nodes.get("Material Output")
texture_node = nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
texture_node.texture = texture

# Connect the nodes
node_tree.links.new(texture_node.outputs[0], output_node.inputs[0])

# Assign the material to an object
object_name = "Cube"
object = bpy.data.objects.get(object_name)
if object is not None:
    object.data.materials.clear()
    object.data.materials.append(material)

# Render the scene
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Function to update the webpage texture
def update_webpage_texture():
    # Navigate to the webpage
    driver.get("localhost:some adress my page is hosted on")

    # Capture a screenshot of the webpage
    screenshot_path = "screenshot.png"
    driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)

    # Update the texture image
    texture.image = bpy.data.images.load(screenshot_path)
    texture.image.reload()

# Update the webpage texture
update_webpage_texture()

# Set up an update handler
def frame_change_handler(scene):
    # Update the webpage texture
    update_webpage_texture()

# Add the update handler to the frame change event
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(frame_change_handler)
```

,whilst theoretically working (positioning the image on some screen-filling plane) this approach is very inefficient, resulting in Blender running at about half a frame per second.

I am now asking, if there is a better approach, like using the webviews framebuffer directly (however that would be possible) by sharing gpu-memory between Blender and my running Browser instance.

Any ideas on tackling this problem? Or is this just a stupid idea, the Blender scripting API isn't meant for?

Comment: I guess it's IO that's taking very long, saving the png then reading it back. Maybe you can write directly to a `bpy.types.Image` pixels ?

Comment: @Gorgious Your idea should certainly yield a speedup. However I even tried just changing one of pixels of the image (`img.pixels[0:4] = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0]`), in blenders `frame_change_pre` handler and already saw massive framedrops, since the whole texture got read from the gpu to the cpu and back.

Comment: yeah you want to use `foreach_set`